# How to render a model in table form, and select some of them using checkbox using django?

Tags: django, checkbox, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model called `ItemBatch`

```
# item upload
class ItemBatch(models.Model):

    ttypes =(('Open','Open'),('Container','Container'),('Trailer','Trailer'),('All','All'))
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_by')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pid = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    length = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    width = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    height = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    volume = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    weight = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    truck_type = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=0, choices=ttypes)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(max_length=100, blank=True,default=now)
    rtd = models.BooleanField(default=False)   #ready to dispatch checkbox


    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

And I am using this views function to render it:

```
@method_decorator([login_required, teacher_required], name='dispatch')
class UploadedItems(ListView):
    model = ItemBatch
    ordering = ('name',)
    context_object_name = 'items'
    template_name = 'classroom/teachers/item_list.html'

    def get_queryset (self):
        return ItemBatch.objects.filter(uploaded_by=self.request.user)
```

I am rendering this table in a template and getting this:

[image: img]

This is the code in the template:

```
{% for quiz in last %}
                    <tr>

                        <form method="post" novalidate>
                            {% csrf_token %}

                            <td class="align-middle"><input type="checkbox" value="{{ quiz.pid }}"></td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.name }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.pid }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.quantity }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.length }}x{{ quiz.width }}x{{ quiz.height }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.volume }}/{{ quiz.weight }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.origin }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.destination }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.time|naturaltime }}</td>
                        </form>
                    </tr>
                {% empty %}
```

---

### What I tried

As you can see, I have created a form inside the table and also included a checkbox. But, I am not able to take the output of the that checkbox in any way. How can I let the user select a few items, and get that data returned to me in any way so I can use it another function ? If the checkbox can just give me the id or pk value, I will be able to reverse it with the appropriate object, but I can't create an input form on a table which already is an output render of another function. Is this the correct way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a submit button at the end of your form, and inside the form tag specify the action and map it to a django view.

Also, you need to moove out your form tags outside of the for loop.

Should look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'your_url_name'%}" novalidate>
{% csrf_token %}
{% for quiz in last %}
    <tr>
        <td class="align-middle"><input name='quiz-pids' id='checkbox-{{forloop.counter}}' type="checkbox" value="{{ quiz.pid }}"></td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.name }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.pid }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.quantity }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.length }}x{{ quiz.width }}x{{ quiz.height }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.volume }}/{{ quiz.weight }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.origin }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.destination }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ quiz.time|naturaltime }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value='Do something'>
</form>
```

In you urls add to path:

```
path('your-url', views.YourView.as_view(), name='your_url_name'),
```

Your View:

```
class YourView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #get the selected quizs
        quizs = request.POST.getlist('quiz-pids')
        #retrieves thoses quizes from the database:
        items = ItemBatch.objects.filter(pid__in=quizs)
        #do something with each of them:
        for item_batch in items:
            #do something
            pass
```

Comment: I was able to get the items selected, but the it shows me this error `The view classroom.views.teachers.UploadedItems didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead`. How to fix this ??

Comment: Also, I don't understand the urls.py part. I already have my `UploadedItems` function using  `path('myitems/', teachers.UploadedItems.as_view(), name='upload_batch'),` . Do I add the new function post there ?

Comment: You need to make a new view and add the new urls corresponding to that view

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. I did not create a new view though. But, I was wondering, when the function returned the Pids of items, I converted them into objects and passed that queryset of objects to another function of mine, but it am unable to do so. Any ideas ? Error says `'list' object has no attribute 'user'` Should I post another question ? The function I am passing to does not have anything to do with `user` at all...

Comment: You should post another question, where you can show the new code you have with a new question. If you edit the post then the answeer will not be relevant for helping future people.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong here.

Firstly you need a single form around all of the options, not one form per row.
And secondly you need a `name` attribute in your input element, so that the browser knows how to send it to the backend.

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
{% csrf_token %}
{% for quiz in last %}
    <tr>
        <td class="align-middle"><input type="checkbox" name="pids" value="{{ quiz.pid }}"></td>
        ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now in your view you can get the submitted values via `self.request.POST.getlist('pids')` - for instance, you could use that to filter the queryset via `ItemBatch.objects.filter(pid__in=self.request.POST.getlist('pids'))`.